# Jetpack Compose Dynamic Spacer Height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose version 1.0.2 (latest stable as of today).

I have a `Column` of multiple `LazyRows`, which has an `Image` and two `Text`.

[image]

See the structure below (simplified)

```kotlin
val topicList: List<Topics>


Column {
    topicList.forEach { topic ->

        val showList: List<Show> = topic.shows

        Column {
            Text(text = topic.title)

            LazyRow {
                items(showList) { show ->
                    Column {
                        Image()
                        Text(text = show.title)
                        Text(text = show.info)
                    }
                }
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.height(32.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `Text` composables with `show.title` and `show.info` can be multiple lines, and as each item is lazy loaded, the height is not calculated until it shows up on the screen. As a result, the next row's `y` position jumps around.

To understand what's going on, please see this video: [Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZKP9x8gqAgiXcH7BwGuoGSk6iOR7KVo/view?usp=sharing)

How can I dynamically calculate the `Spacer`'s height so that they are not jumping? I know the easy solution would be just giving a fixed height, but some texts are just one liner and those will have bigger gaps so it's not really ideal for me I think.

Comment: Well is that not what exactly is happening here? The height is being dynamically calculated based on the text values. I fail to understand what you are trying to get here. Please elaborate further.

Comment: @MARSK yes, the behavior is showing exactly how it's intended to behave according to my code. The desired behavior is that somehow full height is already known before the potential longer height text composables are known, so I can adjust height of the Spacer composable accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. I thought so, but I got confused when you made the point that it would not look nice if the text is small but the height is still large, leaving an empty space.

Comment: @MARSK sorry I made you confused. I was looking for some ways to adjust Spacer's height based on the Text composables' heights. So to users eyes, the row below current row doesn't jump around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the height of a `LazyRow`, you need to know all the dimensions of the elements. A straightforward solution would be to place them all under `LazyRow` using `Box`, in this case the size would be determined by the maximum of them.

But this solution requires a lot of resources, especially if you have a lot of objects. Instead, I suggest that you limit both `info` and `title` by the number of maximum lines, say 2 pieces, and calculate the maximum size given that both texts will have the maximum number of lines.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopicList(topicList: List<Topics>) {
    Column {
        topicList.forEach { topic ->
            val showList = topic.shows
            Column {
                Text(text = topic.title)
                Box {
                    ShowCell(
                        placeholderShow,
                        modifier = Modifier.alpha(0f)
                    )
                    LazyRow(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
                    ) {
                        items(showList) { show ->
                            ShowCell(show)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShowCell(
    show: Show,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .width(200.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(show.image),
            contentDescription = "...",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(2f)
        )
        Text(
            show.title,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            maxLines = titleMaxLines,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        )
        Text(
            text = show.info,
            maxLines = infoMaxLines,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        )
    }
}

private const val titleMaxLines = 2
private const val infoMaxLines = 2
private val placeholderShow = Show(
    image = "",
    title = List(titleMaxLines) { '\n' }.joinToString(separator = ""),
    info = List(titleMaxLines) { '\n' }.joinToString(separator = ""),
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This seem like the most viable solution. Although not desired, it would still save some resources by not using plain `Row` and give up the lazy load (especially when the requirement can't change). Thank you very much! Didn't think to utilize some type of placeholder :). Only downside besides using up resources would be if there's ever case where all shows have only one line of title and info, it will just look like it has bigger margin lol

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh You're welcome. I think this method is the most performant: Compose only needs to calculate the size of the placeholder view once, and since texts only contain new line characters, it takes as little time as possible. Also it's not gonna recalculate it on recompositions, since parameter is constant. If this solved your question, please accept it=)